# Plus one leetcode

Tags: java

I am doing a question on leetcode, [66. Plus One](https://leetcode.com/problems/plus-one/).

> You are given a large integer represented as integer array `digits`, where each `digits[i]` is the `i`th digit of the integer. The digits are ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.
>
> Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of digits.
>
> **Example 1**
>
> - Input: `digits = [1,2,3]`
> - Output: `[1,2,4]`
>
>   Explanation: The array represents the integer 123.
>   Incrementing by one gives 123 + 1 = 124.
>   Thus, the result should be `[1,2,4]`.

My solution is:

```
class Solution {  
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {  
        int num = 0;  
        for (int a : digits) {  
            num = 10*num + a;  
        }  
        int n=num+1;  
        String str=String.valueOf(n);  
        int arr[]=new int[str.length()];  
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){  
            arr[i]=str.charAt(i)-'0';  
        }  
        return arr;  
    }
}
```

I am getting many test cases failed, one being:

```
Input:
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]  
Output:
[1,2,8,6,6,0,8,6,1,9]  
Expected:
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1]
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 8):

Think before you leap. And consider the edges.

Why would they do the seemingly idiotic move of storing an number, digit by digit, in an int array? Makes no sense, right?

Except... computers aren't magic. `int` can't represent **any** number. A computer's storage is *not* infinite. Specifically, an `int` covers 32 bits (4 bytes), and thus can only represent at most 2^32 different numbers. int 'uses' its alloted space of 2^32 by dividing it evenly amongst positive and negative numbers, but negative numbers get one more (because the '0' is in the positive space). In other words, all numbers from -2^31 to +2^31-1, inclusive.

**9876543210 is larger than that**.

You're trying to turn that array of digits into an `int` and that is a dead end. Once you do that, you get wrong answers and there is no fixing this. your algorithm is wrong. You can figure this stuff out, and you should always do that with leetcode-style problems, by *first* carefully reading the assignment. The assignment covers the limits. It says how large these arrays can be, and I'm sure it says that they can be quite large; large enough that the number inside it is larger than 2^31-1. Probably larger than 2^63-1 (which a `long` can reach).

Then you know the algorithm you need to write can't involve 'turn it into an `int` first'. That's usually the point (many problems are trivial if small, but become interesting once you make things large).

The algorithm they want you to write must not involve any conversion whatsoever. Increment the array in place. This isn't hard (just think about it: **without** converting **anything**, how do you turn [1, 2, 3] into [1, 2, 4]? That should be simple. Then think about how to deal with [1, 9, 9]. Finally, think about how to deal with [9, 9, 9]. Then you've covered all the cases and you have your answer.

Comment: "_by first carefully reading the assignment_" - this is why 99% failures occur. We've gotten so used to the **TL:DR** that we (I should say at least "I") have become so lazy, we don't want to read anymore. OP, if nothing else sticks in your mind, let this advice be the ONE things that does.

Answer (score 1):

In continuation to the [detailed explanation of rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685945/68587), in case you are interested in code for the problem.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        int size = digits.length;
        int i=0;
    
        for(i = size-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            if (digits[i] != 9) {
                digits[i] += 1;
                break;
            } else {
                digits[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        
        if(i == -1) {
            int[] newDigits = new int[size+1];
            newDigits[0] = 1;
            return newDigits;
        }
        
        return digits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty trivial task, but in some test cases the value is too high to represent even as `long`, so the best candidate is `BigInteger`.

```java
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    BigInteger val = BigInteger.ZERO;

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++)
        val = val.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(BigInteger.valueOf(digits[i]));

    val = val.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    String str = val.toString();

    digits = str.length() == digits.length ? digits : new int[str.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++)
        digits[i] = str.charAt(i) - '0';

    return digits;   
}
```

***P.S.** Sure, you can do this without `BigInteger`.*

```java
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    boolean carry = true;

    for (int i = digits.length - 1; carry && i >= 0; i--) {
        carry = digits[i] == 9;
        digits[i] = carry ? 0 : digits[i] + 1;
    }

    if (carry) {
        int[] tmp = new int[digits.length + 1];
        tmp[0] = 1;
        System.arraycopy(digits, 0, tmp, 1, digits.length);
        digits = tmp;
    }

    return digits;
}
```

Comment: should be `BigInteger` :)

Comment: Word of advice... while this advice is correct, if the solution doesn't specifically mention using `BigInteger`, work on a solution that does not use it. Having done some coding problems recently, I have come across problems that _specifically_ call for you to use these specialized classes. When you run the code it will work regardless, but the skill the problem is supposed to help you develop won't improve (and might cost you fail that related interview question).

Comment: Just look at the problem and "large integer" appears in bold letters. This **_might_** imply using _BigInteger_. This type of emphasis is a clue. I still think you should try with and without. Remember, the edge case in this situation is when the given `int` is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` any other value incremented by one should be a straight conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a mileage counter in a car. How does it work?
Whenever a 9 turns around, it turns the number left to it too.

So for incrementing by one, you'd start from the right, increment by one and if you incremented it to a 10, set it to a 0 instead and continue with the next digit to the left. If you reached the leftmost digit and still didnt finish, add a 1 to the left and set everything else to 0.

Example:

```
   8
   9 <- incremented rightmost
  10 <- 9 turned to a 10, leftmost digit reached, add a 1 to the left and set everything else to 0
...
  18
  19 <- incremented rightmost
  20 <- 9 turned to a 10, set to 0 instead, increment the next one to the left (1 -> 2), finished
...
 108
 109 <- incremented rightmost
 110 <- 9 turned to a 10, set to 0 instead, increment the next one to the left (1 -> 2), finished
...
 998
 999 <- incremented rightmost
1000 <- 9 turned to a 10, set to 0 instead, increment the next one to the left, turned to a 10 too, set to 0 instead, ...
```

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] digits = new int[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            digits = plusOne(digits);
            System.out.println(IntStream.of(digits).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()));
        }
    }

    public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        boolean finished = false;

        for (int i = digits.length - 1; !finished && i >= 0; i--) {
            if (++digits[i] % 10 == 0) {
                digits[i] = 0;
            } else {
                finished = true;
            }
        }

        if (!finished) {
            // not finished after exiting the loop: every digit was turned from a 9 to a 10 -> we need one digit more
            // initialize a new array with a length of 1 more digit, set the leftmost (index 0) to 1 (everything else is 0 by default)
            digits = new int[digits.length + 1];
            digits[0] = 1;
        }

        return digits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**plus one in leetcode solve on dart language**

```
class Solution {
    List<int>  plusOne(List<int> digits) {
      for(int i=digits.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
        if(digits[i] < 9){
            ++digits[i];
            return digits;
          }
        digits[i]=0;
      }
      List<int> ans = List.filled(digits.length+1, 0);
      ans[0]=1;
      return ans;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is my solution:**
Runtime: 0 ms, faster than 100.00% of Java online submissions for Plus One.
Memory Usage: 40.8 MB, less than 92.31% of Java online submissions for Plus One. for Plus One.

```
  public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        for(int i=digits.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if(digits[i]<9) {
                digits[i]=digits[i]+1;
                return digits;
            }else {
                digits[i]=0;
                if(i==0) {
                    digits= new int[digits.length+1];
                    digits[0]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        return digits;
     }
```

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow isn't merely to collect answers to Leetcode questions. Can you explain what the problem is with the OP's code and how your code fixes it?

Answer (score -1):

**My solution:**
**Runtime**: 0 ms, **Memory Usage**: 2.1 MB,
**play.golang link**: https://go.dev/play/p/Vm28BdaIi2x

```
// function to add one digit based on diff scenarios
func plusOne(digits []int) []int {
    i := len(digits) - 1

    // while the index is valid and the value at [i] ==
    // 9 set it as 0 and move index to previous value
    for i >= 0 && digits[i] == 9 {
        digits[i] = 0
        i--
    }
    if i < 0 {
        //leveraging golang's simplicity with append internal method for array
        return append([]int{1}, digits...)
    } else {
        digits[i]++
    }
    return digits
}
```

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow isn't merely to collect answers to Leetcode questions. Can you explain what the problem is with the OP's code and how your code fixes it?